# How to get list of transaction for ERC20 token address?

Tags: etherscan

Can anyone please help me to get list of transaction for ERC20 token similar to

https://api-ropsten.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0xd39bdb16d138e5219d013cba3d94c327bd246302&sort=asc

This is my ERC20 token address : 0xd39bdb16d138e5219d013cba3d94c327bd246302

I tried with this

http://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=tokentx&address=0xd39bdb16d138e5219d013cba3d94c327bd246302&startblock=0&endblock=999999999&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken

But am getting **no transactions found**

[image]

But i can see transactions in etherscan

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. Change `module=account` to `module=logs`
2. Change `action=tokentx` to `action=getLogs`
3. Add `topic0=0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef`

The last one is the hash of an ERC20 `Transfer` event.

You can obtain it programmatically, for example, using web3.js v1.x:

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const TRANSFER_EVENT = Web3.utils.keccak256("Transfer(address,address,uint256)");
console.log(TRANSFER_EVENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Through web3 code, when you query a particular transaction using 
web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(id)

The response will contain a input parameter, check input.substring(0,10) == '0xa9059cbb' to ensure it is an erc20 transaction

Then you need to check input.substring(34,75) to get "to" address.

Answer (score 0):

Developer Advocate at Alchemy here :)

You can do this with the `getAssetTransfers` endpoint from the [Alchemy Transfers API](https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/alchemy-getassettransfers), which the [Alchemy SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/alchemy-sdk) has support for.

For example, in javascript:

```js
// Setup: npm install alchemy-sdk
const alchemySdk = require("alchemy-sdk");
const Alchemy = alchemySdk.Alchemy;
const Network = alchemySdk.Network;

(async function main() {
  // Configure the Alchemy SDK instance with an https://www.alchemy.com API key.
  const config = {
    apiKey: "your api key",
    network: Network.ETH_MAINNET,
  };
  const alchemy = new Alchemy(config);

  // Define the address and ERC20 token contract I care about.
  const USDCaddress = "0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48";
  const thatguyintech = "thatguyintech.eth";

  // Fetch transactions going into the desired address.
  const usdcTransfersToAlbert = await alchemy.core.getAssetTransfers({
    toAddress: thatguyintech,
    contractAddresses: [USDCaddress],
    category: ["erc20"],
  });

  console.log("transfers to me: ", usdcTransfersToAlbert);

  // Fetch transactions leaving from the desired address.
  const usdcTransfersFromAlbert = await alchemy.core.getAssetTransfers({
    fromAddress: thatguyintech,
    contractAddresses: [USDCaddress],
    category: ["erc20"],
  });

  console.log("transfers from me: ", usdcTransfersFromAlbert);
})();
```

This would return all the USDC-related transactions for `thatguyintech.eth` (there's ENS resolution too, which is super nice :D )

```bash
transfers to me:  {
  transfers: [
    {
      blockNum: '0xc59520',
      uniqueId: '0xe1ccb0199953c1e2bdd23a40d272f9c8fab9b29cfe52c832569d8511ef689d5f:log:290',
      hash: '0xe1ccb0199953c1e2bdd23a40d272f9c8fab9b29cfe52c832569d8511ef689d5f',
      from: '0x88e6a0c2ddd26feeb64f039a2c41296fcb3f5640',
      to: '0xf5fff32cf83a1a614e15f25ce55b0c0a6b5f8f2c',
      value: 246.311717,
      erc721TokenId: null,
      erc1155Metadata: null,
      tokenId: null,
      asset: 'USDC',
      category: 'erc20',
      rawContract: [Object]
    },
  ...
  ]
}
transfers from me:  {
  transfers: [
    {
      blockNum: '0xd2ad27',
      uniqueId: '0x0da90c9c984f764008b298920ff8d0f1c5cfdabde52af4f6caf0f4c94fdccb0a:log:443',
      hash: '0x0da90c9c984f764008b298920ff8d0f1c5cfdabde52af4f6caf0f4c94fdccb0a',
      from: '0xf5fff32cf83a1a614e15f25ce55b0c0a6b5f8f2c',
      to: '0x93fbe19d6fe3eb7618d9fd4318899c4f51b081c7',
      value: 100,
      erc721TokenId: null,
      erc1155Metadata: null,
      tokenId: null,
      asset: 'USDC',
      category: 'erc20',
      rawContract: [Object]
    },
  ...
  ]
}
```

You can switch across other supported networks by changing the `network` attribute in the `config`.

i.e. with these options:

```js
// from node_modules/alchemy-sdk/dist/src/types/types.d.ts
export declare enum Network {
    ETH_MAINNET = "eth-mainnet",
    ETH_GOERLI = "eth-goerli",
    OPT_MAINNET = "opt-mainnet",
    OPT_GOERLI = "opt-goerli",
    ARB_MAINNET = "arb-mainnet",
    ARB_GOERLI = "arb-goerli",
    MATIC_MAINNET = "polygon-mainnet",
    MATIC_MUMBAI = "polygon-mumbai",
    ASTAR_MAINNET = "astar-mainnet"
}
```

Hope that helps!